# How to reproduce Java MessageDigest SHA-1 secret key to be used in MySQL AES_encrypt

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, aes

I have a function to prepare secret key for encryption and decryption using Java:

```java
public void prepareSecreteKey(String theKey) {
    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
        key = theKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        System.out.println(new String(key, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, for the old records from database, I would like to manually encrypt using a MySQL query. I have tried using the query below, but the result is different from the result by the Java application.

```sql
select to_base64(aes_encrypt('123456789032', 'aesEncryptionKey'));
```

Anyone can advise? or is there any other method to encrypt the existing record in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES only allows binary keys of 128, 192 or 256 bit length.

However, in older versions of MySQL  (<8.x.x) you were expected to provide a string (key_str) as key when using the `aes_encrypt(str,key_str)` method. Behind the scenes MySQL would then turn this string into a binary key in an undocumented way. Any attempt to replicate this outside of MySQL would require you to figure out how this is done.

This way of providing keys is now discouraged in the MySQL documentation (for a good reason) - and many additional options have been introduced to the `aes_encrypt(...)` method, that allows you to provide a proper key derivation function (KDF), etc. You should read up on some of the newer [MySQL Encryption and Compression Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) in the MySQL documentation.